# Rowediting plugin strange behavior when adding a new row or editing an existing row

Tags: extjs, plugins, extjs6

Rowediting plugin strange behavior when adding a new row or editing an existing row for the first time (after render component): incorrect editor size and off-center buttons.
Is it a bug?
If it is a bug, is there any solution to this problem?

Ext JS 6.7.0

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2sqf

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem once and while I do not have a detailed answer, I have a couple of solutions.

That issue happens when you are using a store with `inline data` (without a proper Ext.data.Model defined), and you are adding a new record instantiated with `Ext.data.Model`.

So here are two solutions:

**First solution: Adding inline data**

Rather than adding an instance of `Ext.data.Model`, you add simple json data with the required fields.

```
  // in your handler...

  // create the record as json
  jsonRecord =  {
     name: '',
     email: '',
     phone: ''
  }

  // Adding to the store converts the json data into records
  const addedRecords = store.add(jsonRecord);

  // Since we are only adding a single record, we edit the idx 0
  rowediting.startEdit(addedRecords[0]);
```

**Second solution: Define a Model for your data**

```
Ext.define('YourModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'email',   type: 'string'},
        {name: 'phone', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

And use this model to create your store...

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    model: 'YourModel',          // Set model here
    // fields:[ 'name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
        { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
        { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
        { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' }
    ]
});
```

...and to create new records.

```
   // In your handler

   // Create the record with your model
   record = Ext.create('YourModel');

   // Add to the store
   store.add(record);

   // Edit the record instance
   rowediting.startEdit(record);
```

In both approaches, updating the row will also update the newly added record.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks NAmorim. My real app was built with a store and a model, identical to your second solution. However the problem remains. It seems to me a bug.